# Intercept in Quantile Regression

Tags: regression, quantile-regression, intercept

We all know that for the OLS model, if you center both $X$ and $Y$, the estimated intercept would be 0. I was curious if we can do a similar thing for Quantile Regression. Would it be possible if we subtract the accordingly quantile from $X$ and $Y$, and then the estimated intercept would just be 0 as well?

Honestly, I think this process should be wrong, but I can't think of other ways to exclude the intercept for Quantile Regression... Does anyone have thoughts about this question?

Comment: Why do you want to exclude the intercept in your quantile regression? // Why can’t you just omit the intercept from your model?

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the reply! When you say 'omit the intercept' do you mean fitting a QR model without intercept? I could do this, but I am not sure if it is reasonable to do so.

Comment: Or alternatively, why do you not want to estimate an intercept with QR? Is there a particular reason or are you just asking theoretically if this is possible to do in a similar fashion to linear regression + standardization?

Comment: The latter, I was just curious if similar standardization can be done for quantile regression, in a parallel way to OLS.